# Prometheus: ​ Possible to sum counter increase within range of hours, every day?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Basically we have a counter that tracks successful job runs (e.g. `job_success{job_id="abc"}`. What I am trying to do is `sum(increase(...` within a 4h window every day over say, a 30d period.

For example, if a job ran between 9am and 12pm today, the counter would increase by 1. If it ran again today between 12pm and 4pm, the counter would increase by 1 again (2 job runs total for today).

The metrics I want are only the 12pm-4pm, ignoring the 9am-12pm resulting in a today’s total of 1. Ultimately I’m piping this into Grafana to show the higher-ups a nice graph per day that shows the number of jobs that are re-run in the afternoon over a 30d period.

I can do this on the whole day no problem (i.e. `sum(increase(job_success{job_id="abc"}[1d])` = 2 jobs ran today), and I have been experimenting with `and on() hour() > 12 and on() hour <= 16` but haven’t been able to get what I need as a sum value for the day...

Is entirely possible that my approach is incorrect, and really the first question should probably be: is this even possible?

(would also be handy as an alert for any job that ran after 12pm..)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to your task I believe would be:

1. Setup separate dashboard with time range `now/d - 7h` - `now/d - 1d - 8h`. It will set time range to yesterday 15:00 - yesterday 16:00. Explanation on what `now/d` means [here](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/02/03/pro-tip-how-to-use-semi-relative-time-ranges-in-grafana/).
2. Add panel `Stat`
3. Add the following query to this panel

```
increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[4h]) + 
 increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[4h]) offset 1d + 
 increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[4h]) offset 2d + 
 increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[4h]) offset 3d + 
   ...
 increase(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[4h]) offset 29d
```

It will produce number of runs per job. If you want total number of run you can wrap this query into `sum( ... )`

You also can set time range to `now/d + 15h + 59m` - `now/d - 8h` to see data for current date, but in this case panel will be empty until 15:59.

###### Alert rule

To alert increase of your counter after 12:00 you can use simple subtraction with offset:

```
job_success{job_id="abc"} - job_success{job_id="abc"} offset 5m > 0 and on() hour() > 12
```

Or, if you need narrower window, for example 12:00 - 16:00

```
job_success{job_id="abc"} - job_success{job_id="abc"} offset 5m > 0 and on() hour() > 12 < 16
```

###### Off topic notice

If your metrics is a counter, consider naming it according to [best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/). For example `systemname_job_runs_total`.